# Decentralizing an entire website with Cardano?

Tags: decentralized-applications, decentralization

Is it currently possible to decentralize an entire application using Cardano (with the help of other decentralized services)? Coming from the viewpoint of a traditional Web 2.0 background, what are the best decentralized alternatives? Let's say the application has the following features:

1. Users can login/sign up, either using a wallet or a traditional Single Sign On method
2. An alternative to PostgreSQL (i.e. cheap storage with quick read/write). I know IPFS exists, but I've always seen this used to store assets, rather than relational data
3. Hosting of servers (React frontend, Express backend, Nginx reverse proxy, GitHub actions); ideally in Docker containers

If any of these features are possible, what are the pros/cons of decentralization? I imagine the traditional website would be cheaper and more performant, but I'd love to be wrong. Additionally, are there any resources or templates available for easy implementation?

Comment: Have you considered using NoSQL, or are you specifically in need of a relational database?

Comment: @intrinsic-values I don't think NoSQL would be suitable for my project. I'm planning to build a collaborative tool for proposers on Project Catalyst, where users can design "routines" for completing specific tasks. There will be a lot of relational data, which I don't think can be stored using NoSQL. I'm also just more familiar with SQL, so I'd rather use it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [Nami Wallet](https://namiwallet.io/) for users to login directly with their Cardano wallets.
2. [OrbitDB](https://orbitdb.org/) is a serverless, distributed, peer-to-peer database built on top of IPFS.
3. There are different services trying to solve this problem, for example [fleek.co](https://fleek.co/).

And yes, you got the cons right - decentralization is useful, but expensive on performance. All depends on your use case. Just because something is decentralized, doesn't mean it is better.

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a decentralized naming solution on Cardano blockchain:
https://www.adadomains.io/